# p,q is (or are) the number (or numbers) of variables in dataset (or datasets) X and Y, respectively?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I found a similar question [“Numbers” or “number?” Which sentence is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458961/numbers-or-number-which-sentence-is-correct)
However, I found my question a bit more complicated.

So, what's the correct combination of the following sentence?

p,q is/are the number/numbers of variables in dataset/datasets X and Y, respectively?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a domain-specific question that isn't directly related to English. If it is, it's ambiguous. Does `p,q` represent one number or two numbers? I suspect it's two, otherwise the *respectively* part of the sentence wouldn't make much sense, but I don't know how the symbols are being used. Why is there a comma rather than a normal conjunction? Also because of the use of *respectively*, I think it has to be *data sets* plural.

Comment: It'll be confusing. 'p is the number of variables in X and q is the number of variables in Y.'